# How to recompile Ubuntu Toolchain?

Tags: gcc, compilation, toolchain, linux-toolchain, g++4.9

Where I can find environment description and build options that were used on build servers for Ubuntu Toolchain (https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r) 4.1/4.7/4.9/etc? How I can reproduce this flows?

Please suggest how to build same build servers.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Ubuntu repo:

#cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-toolchain-r-test-precise.list

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu precise main
```

Pre build steps:

```
apt-get build-dep -y gcc-4.9-multilib
apt-get source -y gcc-4.9-multilib
dpkg-source -x gcc-4.9_4.9.2-0ubuntu1~12.04.dsc
cd gcc-4.9-4.9.2
```

if you want make same packages:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b
```

If you want provide customized parameters:

```
mkdir -p src && tar -xf gcc-*.tar.xz -C src
cd src && ./contrib/download_prerequisites && cd ..
mkdir -p /opt/dev-tools-4.9
../src/configure --prefix=//opt/dev-tools-4.9 \
-v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~12.04' \
--program-suffix=-4.9 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib \
--libexecdir=//opt/dev-tools-4.9/lib --without-included-gettext \
--enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=//opt/dev-tools-4.9/include/c++/4.9 \
--libdir=//opt/dev-tools-4.9/lib --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes \
--enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror \
--with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64 --with-tune=generic \
--enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu  --with-sysroot=/  --enable-nls

make -j $(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo ) && make install
```